# Is there any way to make the surface look smoother without subdiv or smooth shading?

Tags: materials, shaders, subdivision-surface

I need to smoothen the look of the back of this model as well as the rotating chamber, i know two ways to do so;

1. smooth shading, but it returns some really weird look at turns and curves.
2. subdiv modifier, but i dont want to have too many faces, this is supposed to be a low poly learning experiment.

Please explain in a way a complete amateur could understand, considering this is my first self learning model, as well as me having precisely zero professional education with regard to 3d modelling. Thank You!

[image: Rear diagonal view of the model]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Welcome to Blender Stack Exchange!

From the image you provided, it looks like smooth shading will be the best option. To fix the issues you mentioned, there is an option called auto smooth. It can be found under the *Normals* heading in the *Object Data Properties* panel, which is the little green triangle icon at the bottom right of your image.

If you enable smooth shading then turn on this option, it will keep edges above a certain angle sharp. You may have to adjust this angle, but the default is often pretty good. So for example the edge of the chamber will still have a nice crisp edge.

Here's a comparison that shows the difference between the different shading options. The first is flat shading, the second is smooth shading (with the issues you mention), and the third is smooth shading with auto smooth turned on.
[image]

Comment: that did the trick, thank you very much!